# "Detected 1 CUDA capable device(s)" although there are 1x GTX 1080 and 1x GTX 1080ti installed

Tags: 16.04

I have 2 NVidia graphics card installed, one GTX 1080 and one GTX 1080ti.
After installing CUDA from official https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads site and running this:

`/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`

I get the message:

`Detected 1 CUDA capable device(s)`

How can I enable the second CUDA device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating nvidia driver from version 375 to 381 my second GPU is now detected.